# Why does Entity Framework code-first with table per subclass create multiple joins when it knows the exact type of the joined class?

Tags: entity-framework, join, entity-framework-6

I'm using EF 6.1 and I have a 3-level deep inheritance with about 12 classes inheriting from one base abstract base class called BusinessEntity. In brief, it looks like this:

```
public abstract class BusinessEntity 
{
    [Required, MaxLength(50)]
    public virtual string Name { get; protected set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual long Id { get; protected set; }
    ...
 }
```

then I have Person class which inherits from that:

```
[Table("Person")]
public class Person : BusinessEntity
{
    // other properties here
}
```

then I have another class that has a property Person:

```
public class Notification 
{
    [RequiredForAdd]
    public virtual Person AddressedTo { get; protected set; }
 }
```

When I query the Notifications DBSet, like this:

```
  var notifications = ctx.Notifications.Where(n => n.AddressedTo.Id == userId)
   .Include(n => n.AddressedTo).ToList();
```

I see Sql like this:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Extent1].[NotificationType] AS [NotificationType], 
[Extent1].[NotificationId] AS [NotificationId], 
[Extent1].[EventData] AS [EventData], 
[Extent1].[Message] AS [Message], 
[Extent1].[NotifiedDate] AS [NotifiedDate], 
[Extent1].[ReadDate] AS [ReadDate], 
[Extent1].[CreatedDate] AS [CreatedDate], 
[Extent1].[UpdatedDate] AS [UpdatedDate], 
CASE WHEN ([Join1].[PersonStatus] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) ELSE ''2X0X0X'' END AS [C1], 
[Join1].[BusinessEntityId1] AS [BusinessEntityId], 
[Join1].[EntityType] AS [EntityType], 
[Join1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Join1].[DocumentMode] AS [DocumentMode], 
[Join1].[Headline] AS [Headline], 
[Join1].[LegacyReference] AS [LegacyReference], 
[Join1].[IsDeleted] AS [IsDeleted], 
[Join1].[CreatedDate] AS [CreatedDate1], 
[Join1].[UpdatedDate] AS [UpdatedDate1], 
[Join1].[Email] AS [Email], 
[Join1].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
[Join1].[OtherNames] AS [OtherNames], 
[Join1].[LastName] AS [LastName], 
[Join1].[Title] AS [Title], 
[Join1].[DateOfBirth] AS [DateOfBirth], 
[Join1].[PersonStatus] AS [PersonStatus], 
[Join1].[WindowsName] AS [WindowsName], 
[Join3].[CreatedBy_Id] AS [CreatedBy_Id], 
[Join5].[Currency_Id] AS [Currency_Id], 
[Join7].[UpdatedBy_Id] AS [UpdatedBy_Id], 
CASE WHEN ([Join9].[BusinessEntityId2] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ((CASE WHEN ([Join9].[Discriminator] = N''Person'') THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END) = 1) THEN ''2X0X'' ELSE ''2X0X0X'' END AS [C2], 
[Join9].[BusinessEntityId2] AS [BusinessEntityId1], 
[Join9].[EntityType] AS [EntityType1], 
[Join9].[Name] AS [Name1], 
[Join9].[DocumentMode] AS [DocumentMode1], 
[Join9].[Headline] AS [Headline1], 
[Join9].[LegacyReference] AS [LegacyReference1], 
[Join9].[IsDeleted] AS [IsDeleted1], 
[Join9].[CreatedDate] AS [CreatedDate2], 
[Join9].[UpdatedDate] AS [UpdatedDate2], 
[Join9].[Email] AS [Email1], 
[Join9].[FirstName] AS [FirstName1], 
[Join9].[OtherNames] AS [OtherNames1], 
[Join9].[LastName] AS [LastName1], 
[Join9].[Title] AS [Title1], 
[Join9].[DateOfBirth] AS [DateOfBirth1], 
[Join9].[PersonStatus] AS [PersonStatus1], 
CASE WHEN ([Join9].[BusinessEntityId2] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ((CASE WHEN ([Join9].[Discriminator] = N''Person'') THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END) = 1) THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) ELSE [Join9].[WindowsName] END AS [C3], 
[Join11].[CreatedBy_Id] AS [CreatedBy_Id1], 
[Join13].[Currency_Id] AS [Currency_Id1], 
[Join15].[UpdatedBy_Id] AS [UpdatedBy_Id1], 
[Extent1].[UpdatedBy_Id] AS [UpdatedBy_Id2]
FROM         [dbo].[Notification] AS [Extent1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent2].[BusinessEntityId] AS [BusinessEntityId1], [Extent2].[Email] AS [Email], [Extent2].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], [Extent2].[OtherNames] AS [OtherNames], [Extent2].[LastName] AS [LastName], [Extent2].[Title] AS [Title], [Extent2].[DateOfBirth] AS [DateOfBirth], [Extent2].[PersonStatus] AS [PersonStatus], [Extent2].[Discriminator] AS [Discriminator], [Extent2].[WindowsName] AS [WindowsName], [Extent3].[BusinessEntityId] AS [BusinessEntityId3], [Extent3].[EntityType] AS [EntityType], [Extent3].[Name] AS [Name], [Extent3].[DocumentMode] AS [DocumentMode], [Extent3].[Headline] AS [Headline], [Extent3].[LegacyReference] AS [LegacyReference], [Extent3].[IsDeleted] AS [IsDeleted], [Extent3].[CreatedDate] AS [CreatedDate], [Extent3].[UpdatedDate] AS [UpdatedDate]
    FROM  [dbo].[Person] AS [Extent2]
    INNER JOIN  (SELECT [Var_6].[BusinessEntityId] AS [BusinessEntityId], [Var_6].[EntityType] AS [EntityType], [Var_6].[Name] AS [Name], [Var_6].[DocumentMode] AS [DocumentMode], [Var_6].[Headline] AS [Headline], [Var_6].[LegacyReference] AS [LegacyReference], [Var_6].[IsDeleted] AS [IsDeleted], [Var_6].[CreatedDate] AS [CreatedDate], [Var_6].[UpdatedDate] AS [UpdatedDate]
        FROM [dbo].[BusinessEntity] AS [Var_6]
        WHERE [Var_6].[IsDeleted] <> 1 ) AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[BusinessEntityId] = [Extent3].[BusinessEntityId] ) AS [Join1] ON ([Join1].[Discriminator] = N''User'') AND ([Extent1].[CreatedBy_Id] = [Join1].[BusinessEntityId1])
LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent4].[BusinessEntityId] AS [BusinessEntityId4], [Extent4].[Discriminator] AS [Discriminator], [Extent5].[BusinessEntityId] AS [BusinessEntityId5], [Extent5].[CreatedBy_Id] AS [CreatedBy_Id]
    FROM  [dbo].[Person] AS [Extent4]
    INNER JOIN  (SELECT [Var_7].[BusinessEntityId] AS [BusinessEntityId], [Var_7].[CreatedBy_Id] AS [CreatedBy_Id]
        FROM [dbo].[BusinessEntity] AS [Var_7]
        WHERE [Var_7].[IsDeleted] <> 1 ) AS [Extent5] ON [Extent4].[BusinessEntityId] = [Extent5].[BusinessEntityId] ) AS [Join3] ON ([Join3].[Discriminator] = N''User'') AND ([Extent1].[CreatedBy_Id] = [Join3].[BusinessEntityId4])
LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent6].[BusinessEntityId] AS [BusinessEntityId6], [Extent6].[Discriminator] AS [Discriminator], [Extent7].[BusinessEntityId] AS [BusinessEntityId7], [Extent7].[Currency_Id] AS [Currency_Id]
    FROM  [dbo].[Person] AS [Extent6]
    INNER JOIN  (SELECT [Var_8].[BusinessEntityId] AS [BusinessEntityId], [Var_8].[Currency_Id] AS [Currency_Id]
        FROM [dbo].[BusinessEntity] AS [Var_8]
        WHERE [Var_8].[IsDeleted] <> 1 ) AS [Extent7] ON [Extent6].[BusinessEntityId] = [Extent7].[BusinessEntityId] ) AS [Join5] ON ([Join5].[Discriminator] = N''User'') AND ([Extent1].[CreatedBy_Id] = [Join5].[BusinessEntityId6])
LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent8].[BusinessEntityId] AS [BusinessEntityId8], [Extent8].[Discriminator] AS [Discriminator], [Extent9].[BusinessEntityId] AS [BusinessEntityId9], [Extent9].[UpdatedBy_Id] AS [UpdatedBy_Id]
    FROM  [dbo].[Person] AS [Extent8]
    INNER JOIN  (SELECT [Var_9].[BusinessEntityId] AS [BusinessEntityId], [Var_9].[UpdatedBy_Id] AS [UpdatedBy_Id]
        FROM [dbo].[BusinessEntity] AS [Var_9]
        WHERE [Var_9].[IsDeleted] <> 1 ) AS [Extent9] ON [Extent8].[BusinessEntityId] = [Extent9].[BusinessEntityId] ) AS [Join7] ON ([Join7].[Discriminator] = N''User'') AND ([Extent1].[CreatedBy_Id] = [Join7].[BusinessEntityId8])
LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent10].[BusinessEntityId] AS [BusinessEntityId2], [Extent10].[Email] AS [Email], [Extent10].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], [Extent10].[OtherNames] AS [OtherNames], [Extent10].[LastName] AS [LastName], [Extent10].[Title] AS [Title], [Extent10].[DateOfBirth] AS [DateOfBirth], [Extent10].[PersonStatus] AS [PersonStatus], [Extent10].[Discriminator] AS [Discriminator], [Extent10].[WindowsName] AS [WindowsName], [Extent11].[BusinessEntityId] AS [BusinessEntityId10], [Extent11].[EntityType] AS [EntityType], [Extent11].[Name] AS [Name], [Extent11].[DocumentMode] AS [DocumentMode], [Extent11].[Headline] AS [Headline], [Extent11].[LegacyReference] AS [LegacyReference], [Extent11].[IsDeleted] AS [IsDeleted], [Extent11].[CreatedDate] AS [CreatedDate], [Extent11].[UpdatedDate] AS [UpdatedDate]
    FROM  [dbo].[Person] AS [Extent10]
    INNER JOIN  (SELECT [Var_10].[BusinessEntityId] AS [BusinessEntityId], [Var_10].[EntityType] AS [EntityType], [Var_10].[Name] AS [Name], [Var_10].[DocumentMode] AS [DocumentMode], [Var_10].[Headline] AS [Headline], [Var_10].[LegacyReference] AS [LegacyReference], [Var_10].[IsDeleted] AS [IsDeleted], [Var_10].[CreatedDate] AS [CreatedDate], [Var_10].[UpdatedDate] AS [UpdatedDate]
        FROM [dbo].[BusinessEntity] AS [Var_10]
        WHERE [Var_10].[IsDeleted] <> 1 ) AS [Extent11] ON [Extent10].[BusinessEntityId] = [Extent11].[BusinessEntityId] ) AS [Join9] ON ([Join9].[Discriminator] IN (N''User'',N''Person'')) AND ([Extent1].[AddressedTo_Id] = [Join9].[BusinessEntityId2])
LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent12].[BusinessEntityId] AS [BusinessEntityId11], [Extent12].[Discriminator] AS [Discriminator], [Extent13].[BusinessEntityId] AS [BusinessEntityId12], [Extent13].[CreatedBy_Id] AS [CreatedBy_Id]
    FROM  [dbo].[Person] AS [Extent12]
    INNER JOIN  (SELECT [Var_11].[BusinessEntityId] AS [BusinessEntityId], [Var_11].[CreatedBy_Id] AS [CreatedBy_Id]
        FROM [dbo].[BusinessEntity] AS [Var_11]
        WHERE [Var_11].[IsDeleted] <> 1 ) AS [Extent13] ON [Extent12].[BusinessEntityId] = [Extent13].[BusinessEntityId] ) AS [Join11] ON ([Join11].[Discriminator] IN (N''User'',N''Person'')) AND ([Extent1].[AddressedTo_Id] = [Join11].[BusinessEntityId11])
LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent14].[BusinessEntityId] AS [BusinessEntityId13], [Extent14].[Discriminator] AS [Discriminator], [Extent15].[BusinessEntityId] AS [BusinessEntityId14], [Extent15].[Currency_Id] AS [Currency_Id]
    FROM  [dbo].[Person] AS [Extent14]
    INNER JOIN  (SELECT [Var_12].[BusinessEntityId] AS [BusinessEntityId], [Var_12].[Currency_Id] AS [Currency_Id]
        FROM [dbo].[BusinessEntity] AS [Var_12]
        WHERE [Var_12].[IsDeleted] <> 1 ) AS [Extent15] ON [Extent14].[BusinessEntityId] = [Extent15].[BusinessEntityId] ) AS [Join13] ON ([Join13].[Discriminator] IN (N''User'',N''Person'')) AND ([Extent1].[AddressedTo_Id] = [Join13].[BusinessEntityId13])
LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent16].[BusinessEntityId] AS [BusinessEntityId15], [Extent16].[Discriminator] AS [Discriminator], [Extent17].[BusinessEntityId] AS [BusinessEntityId16], [Extent17].[UpdatedBy_Id] AS [UpdatedBy_Id]
    FROM  [dbo].[Person] AS [Extent16]
    INNER JOIN  (SELECT [Var_13].[BusinessEntityId] AS [BusinessEntityId], [Var_13].[UpdatedBy_Id] AS [UpdatedBy_Id]
        FROM [dbo].[BusinessEntity] AS [Var_13]
        WHERE [Var_13].[IsDeleted] <> 1 ) AS [Extent17] ON [Extent16].[BusinessEntityId] = [Extent17].[BusinessEntityId] ) AS [Join15] ON ([Join15].[Discriminator] IN (N''User'',N''Person'')) AND ([Extent1].[AddressedTo_Id] = [Join15].[BusinessEntityId15])
WHERE ([Extent1].[AddressedTo_Id] = @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[NotifiedDate] IS NULL)',N'@p__linq__0 bigint',@p__linq__0=1
```

It seems to be creating a join to the Person table for each of the subtypes of BusinessEntity but is not actually joining the other subtypes (why would it).

Can anyone explain this behaviour?